# How I can do case sensitive whole word selection in WebStorm?

Tags: ide, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, multipleselection

I am wondering if I can do case sensitive whole word multi-selection in WebStorm.

Selecting some word and pressing <kbd>ALT + J</kbd> do multiple selections but by default it select whole words and part of the bigger words as well.

Answer (score 0):

Currently when the whole word is initially selected by Alt-J on the word under cursor, then the 'whole word' mode is used;
when the initial selection is set manually - by the word selecting - then all occurrences are found (see comments in [IDEA-142248](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142248)).

If you miss a separate action for selecting whole word occurrence, please vote for [IDEA-122069](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122069)